# How to find duplicates in arrayList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have to check duplicate records in ArrayList. In ArrayList each item should have atleast 2 times before insert new Item. Per example

```
Example 1:

AL(0) = '1'
AL(1) = '1'
AL(2) = '2'
AL(3) = '2'
AL(4) = '2'
Method has to return = True, because each value has atleast 2 times in the list.

Example 2:

AL(0) = '1'
AL(1) = '1'
AL(2) = '2'
AL(3) = '3' //Trying to insert new Item, But It should not

Method has to return = 'false', because '2' has 1 time in the list. So I dont 
want insert '3' in ArrayList and return false.
```

Comment: Is the array always sorted? if not, on `[b,b,b,a,a]`, can you insert another `b`? Why are you using an array list when better structures exists (namely, generic ones, such as `List<char>`). and last, do you have a single array, or multiple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ArrayList is ordered, and contains strings of numbers (as illustrated in your post,) then the below function should work:

```
Private Function OKToInsertSorted(ByVal theArrayList As ArrayList, _
                                  ByVal stringToInsert As String) As Boolean

    With theArrayList
        If CInt(stringToInsert) < CInt(.Item(.Count - 1)) Then Return False
        If .Count <= 1 Then
            If stringToInsert = "1" Then Return True Else Return False
        End If
        If .Item(.Count - 1).ToString = .Item(.Count - 2).ToString Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

If your ArrayList is NOT ordered, but still contains strings of numbers (assuming you started with number "1",) then the following function should work:

```
Private Function OKToInsertUNSorted(ByVal theArrayList As ArrayList, _
                                    ByVal stringToInsert As String) As Boolean

    If stringToInsert = "1" Then Return True

    Dim stringToCheck As String = CStr(CInt(stringToInsert) - 1)

    Dim qry = From stringItem In theArrayList _
              Where stringItem.ToString = stringToCheck _
              Group By stringItem Into _
              stringCount = Count()

    For Each result In qry
        If result.stringCount >= 2 Then Return True
    Next

    Return False

End Function
```

I put quite a bit of validation code in the first function based on some assumptions about what you were looking for, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: If stringToInsert = "1" Then Return True ??? Why this statement. ArrayList can contains any number not '1' may be there or '1' may not.

Comment: It was an assumption about the values you would be storing.  "1" was assumed to be the first value in an ordered list, or the lowest value in a non-ordered list.  If that isn't the case, feel free to take it out :)

Comment: What types of values will you be storing in your arraylist?  What limitations/validations are there?  What range?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know much VB.Net, but maybe the following C# code might help (using LINQ).

```
array.Distinct().All(item => array.Count(other => other == item) > 1)
```

I'm guessing the VB syntax (might be wrong)

```
Array.Distinct().All(Function(item) Array.Count(Function(other) other = item) > 1)
```

Here array holds the list item items you're interested about

Comment: Still wrong though, ArrayList isn't generic, and doesn't have most extension methods. You need `.Cast<char>` or `.OfType<char>`, or the native `ArrayList.ToArray()`.

Comment: @Kobi - Man I hate `ArrayList`. They need a loud alert that says use a generic list.

Comment: @ChaosPandion - well, in their defense, you don't have `using System.Collections` by default anymore, but it is surprising to see so many of these questions.

Comment: @Kobi - Let me just add an addendum to my previous comment. I am not really that religious about `ArrayList`. It is just an annoyance for me.

Comment: I had not used AL for such a long time, I had forgotten it's not generic. :( Another (probably better) choice would be using List<T> instead of ArrayList in the first place. No casts, no worries :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following check on arraylist to check if there are duplicate data or not in the arraylist

```
   return arrList.ToArray().Distinct().Count() == arrList.Count;
```

if you want to check before inserting that the data is already present in the arraylist or not use the following check

```
if (!arrList.Contains(data)) {
    arrList.Add(data);                
}
```

Comment: Those are both good options, but unfortunately the OP wants something else; only insert new items if the prev item exists more than once.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply by checking the array list count and distinct count.

```
var isDuplicate = arrayList.Count() > arrayList.Distinct().Count();
```